# Read file that changes name frequently in Java

Tags: java, file, path, glob

I need to read an xml-file that has as dynamic name. File name is something like "1234_employees.xml" in which the digits change daily. There is only one .xml in the folder.

Doesn't <del>regex</del> this work for files/paths?

Something like:

```
File myxml = new File("*employees.xml");
```

Comment: BTW, that's not a regex, but a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Knowing the right term to search for makes everything easier.

Comment: you are right, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `WildcardFileFilter`:

```
File dir = new File(".");
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*employees.xml");

File employeesXml = dir.listFiles(fileFilter)[0];
```

You will need to install this library:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `FilenameFilter` as below

```
for (File inputFile : yourDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith("employees.xml");
        }
})) { 
     // process inputFile here
}
```